# NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x10e0060

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

My application is written in Kotlin and I used raw SQLite and Room as well but both give me the following exception while trying to save items.

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "asteroids")
data class CachedAsteroid(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    var name: String,
    @TypeConverters(CachedEstimatedDiameterConverter::class)
    @Embedded
    var estimatedDiameter: CachedEstimatedDiameter,
    var isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid: Boolean,
    var absoluteMagnitudeH: Float,
    @TypeConverters(CachedCloseApproachDataConverter::class)
    @Embedded
    var closeApproachData: CachedCloseApproachData
)
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface AsteroidDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAsteroids(asteroids: List<CachedAsteroid>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM asteroids WHERE (closeApproachDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)")
    fun getAsteroids(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): Single<List<CachedAsteroid>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM asteroids WHERE name = :asteroidName")
    fun getAsteroidByName(asteroidName: String): Single<CachedAsteroid>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM asteroids")
    fun storedAsteroidsCount(): Single<Int>
}
```

**Exception**

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
 ID #0x10e0060  at
 android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)    at
 android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:989)   at
 android.database.CursorWindow.__constructor__(CursorWindow.java:103)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java)  at
 android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
    at
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
    at
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
    at
 android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
    at
 android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
    at
 androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.hasRoomMasterTable(RoomOpenHelper.java:156)
    at
 androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:124)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:116)     at
 androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
    at
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
    at
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at
 androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
    at
 androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:257)
    at
 com.github.meness.asteroids.cache.AsteroidCacheImpl$saveAsteroids$1.call(AsteroidCacheImpl.kt:33)
    at
 com.github.meness.asteroids.cache.AsteroidCacheImpl$saveAsteroids$1.call(AsteroidCacheImpl.kt:17)
    at
 io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableDefer.subscribeActual(CompletableDefer.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2171)    at
 io.reactivex.Completable.test(Completable.java:2610)
```

**Additional Information**

- **minSdk**: 21
- **targetSdk**: 28
- **compileSdk**: 28
- **Room version**: 2.0.0

Comment: Try file -> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: @AfinasEM That doesn't work

Comment: Please show the loading of the sql database. Around `AsteroidCacheImpl.kt:33` and the resources usages of assets if any related to SQLite.